# Automapping complex types using polymorphism?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using AutoMapper to convert from my own complex types to someone else's slightly more complex types used by their web service API.

Here are my types:

```
namespace Source
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class ExistingClient : Client
    {
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class NewClient : Client
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

and I need to convert these to the following

```
namespace Target
{
    public class WebOrder
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public WebClient { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class WebClient
    {
        public object Item // instance of NewWebClient or ExistingWebClient
    }

    public class ExistingWebClient
    {
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class NewWebClient
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

I've created an AutoMapper profile which includes the following CreateMap call (plus a few more)

```
CreateMap<Source.ExistingClient, Target.ExistingWebClient>();
CreateMap<Source.NewClient, Target.NewWebClient>();
CreateMap<Source.Client, Target.WebClient>();
```

but I'm stuck on how to use polymorphism with `MapTo()` or `ResolveUsing()` to correctly set the Item property, short of replacing the last line with a separate map for each subtype, which seems clumsy and repetitive.

```
CreateMap<Source.NewClient, Target.WebClient>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Item, o => o.MapFrom(s => 
        Mapper.Map<Source.NewClient, Target.NewWebClient>(s)));

CreateMap<Source.ExistingClient, Target.WebClient>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Item, o => o.MapFrom(s => 
        Mapper.Map<Source.ExistingClient, Target.ExistingWebClient>(s)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the neatest way to do it, but I finally settled on using a custom resolver class.

```
public class ClientResolver : IValueResolver<Source.Client, Target.ClientWeb, object>
{
    public object Resolve(Source.Client source, Target.ClientWeb destination, object destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source is Source.NewClient)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Source.NewClient, Target.NewClientWeb>(source as Source.NewClient);
        }
        else if (source is Source.ExistingClient)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Source.ExistingClient, Target.ExistingClientWeb>(source as Source.ExistingClient);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```